# Stop direnv showing all environment variables on load

Tags: direnv

I have `direnv` installed, and I was wondering if there was a way of stopping it from showing all of the environment variables it loads? The output lines it currently shows are:

```
direnv: loading .envrc
direnv: export +FOO +BAR +FOO2 +BAR2 +FOO3 +BAR3 +FOO4 +BAR4
```

I'm fine with having the first line show, but since my second line has something like 50 variables in it, it's slightly annoying to have the lot of them shown *every* time I go into the directory.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to remove the logs entirely by setting `export DIRENV_LOG_FORMAT=` but then the rest of the logs are also missing

Comment: That only affects log messages output by the stdlib. So, in the poster's case, it would only eliminate the output "direnv: loading .envrc", but not the second which lists the exports.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot change that behavior through configuration.

If that behavior was part of the [stdlib](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/blob/master/stdlib.sh), you could override it. In fact, the first ouput, `direnv: loading .envrc` comes from `source_env` which uses `log_status` to output to stderr, so you could override either of `source_env` or `log_status` in `~/.config/direnv/.direnvrc` or `~/.direnvrc`.

However, the second output is coming from [diffString](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/blob/v2.17.0/cmd_export.go#L121) in `cmd_export.go` (via `log_status` in `log.go`). Short of compiling your own, modified version of direnv, I don't see how you can change that behavior as of the current release (v2.17.0).